# comparing strings in list to strings in list

Tags: python, list

I see that the code below can check if a word is

```
list1 = 'this'
compSet = [ 'this','that','thing' ]
if any(list1 in s for s in compSet): print(list1)
```

Now I want to check if a word in a list is in some other list as below:

```
list1 = ['this', 'and', 'that' ]
compSet = [ 'check','that','thing' ]
```

What's the best way to check if words in list1 are in compSet, and doing something over non-existing elements, e.g., appending 'and' to compSet or deleting 'and' from list1?

__________________update___________________

I just found that doing the same thing is not working with sys.path. The code below sometimes works to add the path to sys.path, and sometimes not.

```
myPath = '/some/my path/is here'
if not any( myPath in s for s in sys.path):
    sys.path.insert(0, myPath)
```

Why is this not working? Also, if I want to do the same operation on a set of my paths,

```
myPaths = [ '/some/my path/is here', '/some/my path2/is here' ...]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Re your update, what is not working? Is it giving an error? Perhaps you are just not using backslashes in your `myPath` variable?

Comment: @brianpck Thanks, I updated. The function above to add a path to sys.path works inconsistently. It works sometimes and sometimes not. Maybe it is a specific problem of my environment, I guess... By the way, If I do this adding to path thing over a list of paths with sys.path, is Intersection function is the best to do it?

Comment: If you want to find the paths that are in both lists, then yes, intersection is the best way. With regard to `sys.path`, I recommend asking another question if this is an issue since it's really a separate issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple way to check for the intersection of two lists: convert them to a set and use `intersection`:

```
>>> list1 = ['this', 'and', 'that' ]
>>> compSet = [ 'check','that','thing' ]
>>> set(list1).intersection(compSet)
{'that'}
```

You can also use bitwise operators:

Intersection:

```
>>> set(list1) & set(compSet)
{'that'}
```

Union:

```
>>> set(list1) | set(compSet)
{'this', 'and', 'check', 'thing', 'that'}
```

You can make any of these results a list using `list()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Brian, I just updated my question. Can you please look into it?

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
 >>> l = list(set(list1)-set(compSet))
 >>> l
 ['this', 'and']
```

Comment: Just to clarify; this is showing the words in `list1` that *is not*  in `compSet`, and not which words that is in it.